# Mostrar flecha al hacer hover en un botón

Tags: html, css, botón

quería saber como puedo mostrar una flecha al hacer hover encima de un botón. Pongo un ejemplo: https://www.nutrilorenzo.es (el botón que dice "Quien soy"), quiero mostrar la flecha con esa animación.

A continuación pongo lo que he intentado.

Como véis, me queda un "hueco" en el botón, supongo que es lugar que corresponde a i class="fas fa-chevron-right", quería saber también como puedo eliminar ese espacio tal y como se muestra en la web que he puesto de ejemplo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Ya lo he conseguido, dejo el código editado por si a alguien le sirve. He cambiado el position a absolute y he agregado un padding: right al hacer hover. La animación queda bastante bien.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #e67321;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 11px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ca651c;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.button:hover .fa-chevron-right {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<a class="button" href="">BOTON<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Intenta comentar tu codigo y lo que ya has intentado

Comment: Hola, ya está actualizado, espero que sirva.

Comment: No veo ningún error en lo que muestras, hace exactamente lo que pides. El botón muestra una flecha al poner el mouse sobre él.

Comment: Si te fijas, hay un espacio que ocupa la flecha al estar escondida, entonces, las letras del botón cuando no se hace hover no aparecen centradas, mi intención es encontrar una manera de eliminar ese espacio cuando no se haga hover, es decir, cuando el ratón no este encima del botón y después, al hacer hover, que ese espacio se vuelva a añadir mostrando la flecha.

Comment: Cuando el botón esta escondido, por default, que la flecha esté con `position: absolute`, así no ocupará espacio en el contenedor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes colocar el ícono en posición absoluta cuando no se muestre, y cuando esté mostrándose, lo colocas en posición relativa. El código quedaría así:

```css
body {
          font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
        }


        .button {
          display: block;
          width: 100px;
          margin: 20px auto 0px;
          padding: 10px 0;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: 500;
          color: white;
          border-radius: 2px;
          background-color: #e67321;
          transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .fa-chevron-right {
          position: absolute;
          right: 10px;
          visibility: hidden;
          transition: all 0.5s;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .button:hover {
          background-color: #ca651c;
        }

        .button:hover .fa-chevron-right {
          position: relative;
          visibility: visible;
          right: -5px;
          opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<a class="button" href="">BOTON<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado como dices pero la animación queda poco fluida, he cambiado la posición a absoluta y he agregado un padding: right al hacer hover y para mi gusto queda mejor. De todas maneras, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Es un gusto intentar ayudar.

Comment: Pero si te lo ha resuelto la duda @Tutako aunque la animación no sea exacta como tu quieres, te ha dado la solución, deberías darlle como mínimo por válida la respuesta...

Comment: Se me olvidó dársela como válida. Acabo de entrar al foro y no me manejo mucho. Disculpen.